# Numerically convolve lists in mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, convolution

I have a function $$\chi(x) = \frac{a^2}{a^2 + \left(\frac{d^{2}}{x} + x\left( \frac{ab}{x^{2} - c^2} - 1 \right) \right)^{2}}$$ which I would like to convolve with the Fourier transform of the Hanning window, $H(t)\rightarrow\tilde{H}(\omega)$. I have attempted to do this 'analytically' in Mathematica with

```
Convolve[\chi[x], FourierTransform[HanningWindow[t], t, x], x, y]
```

However this never completes even with assumptions, such as `Assumptions-> x > 0 && y > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0`. Maybe this expression is too difficult, there is maybe no closed form or maybe I don't know enough about how to use `Convolve[...]` effectively.

If anyone has any thoughts about this problem that would be very helpful. Here is the function in, $\chi(x)$, Mathematica code:

```
\[Chi][a_, b_, c_, d_, x_] := a^2/(
 a^2 + (d^2/x + x ((a b)/(x^2 - c^2) - 1))^2)
```

My next approach is to do this numerically. So I will generate two lists one for $\chi(x)$, where I define values for $a$, $b$, and $c$, and one list for $\tilde{H}(\omega)$. I choose some arbitary resolution in $\omega$ as $\delta \omega$.

I then want to make the convolution of the two lists 
$$\{\chi(\omega_{i})\} * \{\tilde{H}(\omega_{i})\}$$,
and maybe this will give me the information I am interested in.

I haven't been able to discover how to make such a convolution with lists in Mathematica -- is this possible?

Comment: Check `ListConvolve`.

Comment: Yours code is wrong? Probably you want:`FourierTransform[HannWindow[x], x, ω]`?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk yes that is true, that's just a typo though. The convolution still doesn't complete.

Comment: I absolutely did! Thanks, I have corrected.

Comment: Can you show your function definition for chi?

Comment: @bills Absolutely! Please see above!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your [`HannWindow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HannWindow.html)and $\chi$ function are Indeterminate at $x=0$ so I created a function that uses the [`Limit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) at $x=0$ or I rearranged the function to eliminate the divide by zero.

I don't know if it is necessary, but I seem to have had better success if I make the function cyclical by mirroring it about it's endpoint before doing the convolution.

The following code will create a numerical ListConvolve and a Manipulate so you can see the effect of parameter changes.

```
window[ω_][x_] = 
  If[x == 0, 1/(
   2 Sqrt[2 π] ω), (-((
     2 I E^(-((I x)/(
       2 ω))) (-1 + E^((
        I x)/ω)) π^2 ω^2 (UnitStep[-ω] - 
        UnitStep[ω]))/(x^3 - 4 π^2 x ω^2)) + 
    2 π DiracDelta[x] UnitStep[-ω] UnitStep[ω])/
   Sqrt[2 π]];
χ[a_, b_, c_, d_][
   x_] := (a^2*x^2)/(d^4 + x^4 + (2*a*b*x^4)/(c^2 - x^2) + 
     a^2*(x^2 + (b^2*x^4)/(c^2 - x^2)^2) + 
     2*d^2*x^2*(-1 + (a*b)/(-c^2 + x^2)));
delta[x0_, xf_, n_] := (xf - x0)/(n - 1)
grid[x0_, xf_, n_] := N@Range[x0, xf, delta[x0, xf, n]]
cyclic = N@(#~Join~Reverse[#] &)@(dummy /@ #) &;
discreteConvolve[startx_, finalx_, npoints_, w_, m_] := 
 Module[{gr, g, wdigitized, mdigitized, conv, discreteConv},
  (* Create the cyclic grid *)
  gr = grid[startx, finalx, npoints];
  g = cyclic@gr;
  (* Digitize the window/kernel *)
  wdigitized = w @@@ g;
  (* Normalization *)
  wdigitized = wdigitized/Total[wdigitized];
  (* Digitize the model *)
  mdigitized = m @@@ g;
  (* Perform the convolution *)
  conv = ListConvolve[wdigitized, mdigitized, {1, -1}, 0];
  discreteConv = Transpose[{gr, conv~Take~npoints}];
  (* Display the results *)
  discreteConv]
Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[
   discreteConvolve[0, finalx, npoints, 
    window[ω], χ[a, b, c, d]], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, finalx}, {0, 1}}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Convolution"}], 
  Plot[χ[a, b, c, d][x], {x, 0, finalx}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, finalx}, {0, 1}}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Model"}]],
 {{ω, 1}, 0.01, 1},
 {{a, 1}, 0, 6},
 {{b, 1}, 0, 6},
 {{c, 1}, 0, 6},
 {{d, 1}, 0, 6},
 {{finalx, 30}, 10, 100},
 {{npoints, 200}, 100, 5000, 100}
 ]
```

[image: Manipulate Example]

Comment: Wow this is really neat!! It's okay though as $x$ is always real and positive. Seriously this is really nice.

Comment: If I could ask one question before I accept your answer, what is the meaning of the parameter omega you introduce. I.e. I guess this is related to the Fourier transform if the window, but why is it a variable? Is this the size of the transformed window in frequency space?

Comment: @QuantumPenguin Thank you for your kind words.  You are correct.  Omega was a term that I introduced to vary the width of the window function.  I was not sure what the nominal values of the a-d parameters were and with my range choice, an omega of 1 excessively broadened the peaks.  I did it to convince myself that ListConvolve would sharpen as I narrowed the window function.